# Pandas fill missing values in dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I cannot find a pandas function (which I had seen before) to substitute the NaN's in a dataframe with values from another dataframe (assuming a common index which can be specified). Any help?

Comment: Sounds Like you want a merge.  Please show some example scenarios.

Comment: found it! I wanted to use combine_first

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html

Comment: `fillna` has a `value` argument which can be used to map missing values by common index, but this expects the argument type to be `Series` or `dict`, not `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have two DataFrames of the same shape, then:

```
df[df.isnull()] = d2
```

Will do the trick.

[image: visual representation]

Only locations where `df.isnull()` evaluates to `True` (highlighted in green) will be eligible for assignment.

In practice, the DataFrames aren't always the same size / shape, and transforming methods (especially `.shift()`) are useful.

Data coming in is invariably dirty, incomplete, or inconsistent. Par for the course. There's a pretty extensive pandas [tutorial and associated cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html) for dealing with these situations.

Comment: Note, you may need to do the following: df[df.isnull()] = d2.values

Answer (score 32):

As I just learned, there is a [`DataFrame.combine_first()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method, which does precisely this, with the additional property that if your updating data frame `d2` is bigger than your original `df`, the additional rows and columns are added, as well.

```
df = df.combine_first(d2)
```

Answer (score 30):

This should be as simple as

```
df.fillna(d2)
```

Comment: The cleanest solution to the problem in 2021, should be the accepted answer. Note that the column names need to be the same in both dataframes.

Comment: does fillna() fill missing values from other dataset based on the index position?

Answer (score 13):

A dedicated method for this is [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

Quoted from the documentation:

> Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.
>   Aligns on indices. There is no return value.

Important to note is that this method will modify your data **inplace**. So it will overwrite your updated dataframe.

**Example**:

```
print(df1)
       A    B     C
aaa  NaN  1.0   NaN
bbb  NaN  NaN  10.0
ccc  3.0  NaN   6.0
ddd  NaN  NaN   NaN
eee  NaN  NaN   NaN

print(df2)
         A    B     C
index                
aaa    1.0  1.0   NaN
bbb    NaN  NaN  10.0
eee    NaN  1.0   NaN

# update df1 NaN where there are values in df2
df1.update(df2)
print(df1)
       A    B     C
aaa  1.0  1.0   NaN
bbb  NaN  NaN  10.0
ccc  3.0  NaN   6.0
ddd  NaN  NaN   NaN
eee  NaN  1.0   NaN
```

Notice the updated `NaN` values at intersect `aaa, A` and `eee, B`

Answer (score 7):

[DataFrame.combine_first()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) answers this question exactly.

However, sometimes you want to fill/replace/overwrite some of the non-missing (non-NaN) values of DataFrame A with values from DataFrame B. That question brought me to this page, and the solution is [DataFrame.mask()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
A = B.mask(condition, A)
```

When `condition` is true, the values from A will be used, otherwise B's values will be used.

For example, you could solve the OP's original question with `mask` such that when an element from A is non-NaN, use it, otherwise use the corresponding element from B.

But using [DataFrame.mask()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) you could replace the values of A that fail to meet arbitrary criteria (less than zero? more than 100?) with values from B. So `mask` is more flexible, and overkill for this problem, but I thought it was worthy of mention (I needed it to solve my problem).

It's also important to note that B could be a numpy array instead of a DataFrame. [DataFrame.combine_first()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) requires that B be a DataFrame, but [DataFrame.mask()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) just requires that B's is an NDFrame and its dimensions match A's dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

One important info missing from the other answers is that both `combine_first` and `fillna` match on index, so you have to make the indices of match across the DataFrames for these methods to work.

Oftentimes, there's a need to match on some other column(s) to fill in missing values. In that case, you need to use `set_index` first to make the columns to be matched, the index.

```py
df1 = df1.set_index(cols_to_be_matched).fillna(df2.set_index(cols_to_be_matched)).reset_index()
```

or

```py
df1 = df1.set_index(cols_to_be_matched).combine_first(df2.set_index(cols_to_be_matched)).reset_index()
```

Another option is to use `merge`:

```py
df1 = (df1.merge(df2, on=cols_to_be_matched, how='left', suffixes=('','\x00'))
       .sort_index(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)[df.columns])
```

The idea here is to left-merge and by sorting the columns (we use `'\x00'` as the suffix for columns from `df2` since it's the character with the lowest Unicode value), we make sure the same column values end up next to each other. Then use `bfill` horizontally to update `df1` with values from `df2`.

---

**Example:**

Suppose you had `df1`:

```
   C1 C2   C3  C4
0   1  a  1.0   0
1   1  b  NaN   1
2   2  b  NaN   2
3   2  b  NaN   3
```

and `df2`

```
   C1 C2  C3
0   1  b   2
1   2  b   3
```

and you want to fill in the missing values in `df1` with values in `df2` for each pair of `C1`-`C2` value pair. Then

```py
cols_to_be_matched = ['C1', 'C2']
```

and all of the codes above produce the following output (where the values are indeed filled as required):

```
   C1 C2   C3  C4
0   1  a  1.0   0
1   1  b  2.0   1
2   2  b  3.0   2
3   2  b  3.0   3
```