# How do I fill a DataFrame from another DataFrame, adding rows and replacing nulls?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `pandas.DataFrame`s with overlapping columns and indices, like

```
X = pandas.DataFrame({"A": ["A0", "A1", "A2"], "B": ["B0", None, "B2"]},
                     index=[0, 1, 2])
Y = pandas.DataFrame({"A": [V, "A3"], "B": ["B1", "B3"], "C": ["C1", "C3"]},
                     index=[1, 3])
```

I would like to extend `X` by the values in `Y`, whereever data is missing, keeping the same columns. That is

1. if `V=="A1"` or `pandas.isnull(V)`, I'd like to obtain

   ```
   >>> X.fill_from(Y)
       A     B
   0  A0    B0
   1  A1    B1
   2  A2    B2
   3  A3    B3
   ```

   The value `B1` has been filled from `Y` because the previous value, `None`, is a null value in pandas. Row `3` has been added because all values in that row were not given in `X`, because `X` had no such row.
2. If `V!="A1"`, I want to get an exception raised concerning the fact that the data frames contain incompatible data.

If I was sure my data had no missing data, `pandas.concat((X, Y), join_axes=[X.columns])` would do the extension, and `DataFrame.index.get_duplicates()` would tell me if there were mis-matching rows.

The hard part is making sure that missing data is not taken to be *different from* present data, but can be filled in, and I don't see how to do it without iterating over every possible pair in `get_duplicates()` and copying data manually.

[This question with a similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554934/fill-a-dataframe-with-data-from-another-dataframe) is not really related. Using `X[X.isnull()] = Y`, as in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357379/pandas-fill-missing-values-in-dataframe-from-another-dataframe), does not work with the `get_duplicates()` mis-matching check.

Comment: Just skim-read, but have you tried `combine_first`?

Comment: `combine_first` is looking very good for matching data, thank you. Now I need to see how to get errors thrown for non-matching data (because comparing data frames is not obvious either).

Comment: As @IanS suggested you can call `combine_first` `X.combine_first(Y)[['A','B']]` to achieve what you want

Comment: If you `merge` with `indicator=True` then you can see whether rows are left/right/both `X.merge(Y, how='outer', indicator=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `combine_first` method is half the deal, thanks to @IanS for pointing it out.

```
>>> X.combine_first(Y)[list(X.columns)]
    A   B
0  A0  B0
1  A1  B1
2  A2  B2
3  A3  B3
```

Now, if `V` is nice, we should get the same result when `combine_first`ing in the other direction, otherwise we will get something different. And because `NaN`s do not compare nicely, the whole function is

```
def combine_first_if_matching(X, Y):
    filled = X.combine_first(Y)[list(X.columns)]
    reverse_filled = Y.combine_first(X)[list(X.columns)]
    if ((filled == reverse_filled) | (filled.isnull())).all().all():
        return filled
    else:
        raise ValueError("Overlap of data frames did not match")
```