# Filling null values in pandas based on value in another column conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, nan

how to fill null values in a row based on the value in another column.

```
A  B
0  5 
1  NAN
1  6
0  NAN
```

for the null value in B if coressponding value in A is 0 then fill with the previous value.

````
A  B
0  5 
1  NAN
1  6
0  6

```

it want it to be like this
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas fill missing values in dataframe from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357379/pandas-fill-missing-values-in-dataframe-from-another-dataframe)

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg that question asks about fill null values based on a common index, not based on a condition on another column and the previous value.

Answer (score 3):

`numpy.where` + `isnull` + `ffill`

```
df.assign(
    B=np.where(df.A.eq(0) & df.B.isnull(), df.B.ffill(), df.B)
)
```

```
   A    B
0  0  5.0
1  1  NaN
2  1  6.0
3  0  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using loc,

```
df.loc[df['A'].eq(0), 'B'] = df['B'].ffill()

    A   B
0   0   5
1   1   NaN
2   1   6
3   0   6
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster way (compared to the previous ones):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,1,0], 'B':[5,np.nan,6,np.nan]})

df.B = np.where(df.A==0, df.B.ffill(), df.B)
```

and you get:

```
    A   B
0   0   5.0
1   1   NaN
2   1   6.0
3   0   6.0
```