# Cells operation in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am doing an experiment and want to observe the impact of missing values on the query results. I am doing it using Python Pandas. Consider that I have dataframe `df`. This dataframe is the complete data. My real data consists of many columns and thousands of rows.

I made a copy of `df` to `df_copy`. Then I do an experiment using `df_copy` and `df` is the ground truth. I put some NaN values on `df_copy` randomly.

I have some ideas to fix the missing values on `df_copy` using a heuristic ways. Currently, I can do easily using row operation in pandas. For instance, if I want to fix any rows on `df_copy`, I just can get the row by the id from `df_copy` then drop the row and replace from the `df`.

My question is, how can I do an operation on a cell-based in pandas? For instance, How can I get the index (x,y) from all missing values and when I want to fix a missing cell, I can just replace the value on that cell from the ground truth by calling the index (x,y)

Example:

`df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["x", 2, 3], ["y", 5, 6], ["z", 8, 9]]),
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


    a   b   c
0   x   2   3
1   y   5   6
2   z   8   9
```

df_copy

```
df_copy = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["x", np.nan, 3], ["y", 5, np.nan], [np.nan, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


    a   b   c
0   x   nan 3
1   y   5   nan
2   nan 8   9
```

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357379/pandas-fill-missing-values-in-dataframe-from-another-dataframe

Comment: You can get the missings' indices with `list(zip(*np.where(df.isna())))`