# Best way to impute nulls (np.nan) in Pandas DataFrame with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Let's say I have my main DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
'Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03','2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'] ,
'Values': [11, np.nan, np.nan, 13, np.nan, np.nan, 15, np.nan, np.nan], 
'Random_Col': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

I want to fill the np.nan values with values from another dataframe that is not the same shape. The values have to match on "ID" and "Date".

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 
'Date': ['2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03','2021-01-02','2021-01-03'],
'Values': [16, 19, 14, 14, 19, 18]})
```

What's the best way to do this?

I experimented with df.update(), but I'm not that works since the dataframes do not have the same number of rows. Am I wrong about this?

I could also use pd.merge(), but then I end up with multiple versions of each column and have to .fillna() for each specific column with the 2nd column with the new values. This would be fine if I only had 1 column of data to do this for, but I have dozens.

Is there a simpler way that I haven't considered?

Comment: If you know each index will match `pandas.Series.combine_first` is a worth a look

Comment: not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357379/pandas-fill-missing-values-in-dataframe-from-another-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `merge` + `sort_index` + `bfill` to fill the missing data in `df`, then reindex with `df.columns`. Since `'\x00'` has the lowest value, the sorting should place the same column names next to each other.

```
out = (df.merge(new_df, on=['ID','Date'], how='left', suffixes=('','\x00'))
       .sort_index(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)[df.columns])
```

Output:

```
  ID        Date Values Random_Col
0  1  2021-01-01   11.0          0
1  1  2021-01-02   16.0          0
2  1  2021-01-03   19.0          0
3  2  2021-01-01   13.0          0
4  2  2021-01-02   14.0          0
5  2  2021-01-03   14.0          0
6  3  2021-01-01   15.0          0
7  3  2021-01-02   19.0          0
8  3  2021-01-03   18.0          0
```

Comment: This is interesting, but this solution only works if all the columns are adjacent to one another, correct? It works for my example, but in a real world exercise with dozens of columns like this, and I have something like columns = ['ID', 'Date', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', etc], then it would simply impute nulls from 'col1' with data from 'col2', rather than 'col1_', right?

Comment: That does work. Quite clever! Thank you!