Join 2 dataframes with same column but different values (Python)
I want to join 2 tables, with same column names, table 1 has data universe with some NA's, table 2 has valid data for which table 1 has NA values.
I want to populate NA value in table 1 based on table 2 using joins.
Edit: Table 2 doesn't contain all columns as Table 1
I tried this
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8,]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame([[7, 8, 9]], columns=['A','B','C'])

data1.merge(data2, on=['A','B'], how='left')

Output I expect:

Output I got:


What if you had data2 = pd.DataFrame([[None, 8, 9]], columns=['A','B','C'])?

Looks like you might want pd.concat([data1, data2]).groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).first()

I'm joining based on column A and B, if "None" is in column A, then the merge won't work

have you tried this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357685/12934163?

screenshots are not easy to work with. Try to copy in the tables. Besides that the question looks good

no, concat won't work. Table 2 doesn't contain all the columns as table 1..

@Varsha can you clarify your example? It works well with the current one.

@TiTo, data1.combine_first(data2) solved the problem. Thank you

@mozway, data1.combine_first(data2) solved the problem. Thank you

If you're always "joining" based on known columns, then you probably want to concat and groupby.first (or last if you have different values and want to give priority to the new one):
out = pd.concat([data1, data2]).groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).first()

Alternatively:
cols = ['A', 'B']

out = (data1.set_index(cols)
       .combine_first(data2.set_index(cols))
       .reset_index()
      )

Or, assuming you have range index in data1 and no duplicates for A/B in data2 (if not this will produce incorrect results), using a merge:
out = data1.combine_first(data1[cols].merge(data2, how='left'))

Output:
   A  B    C
0  1  2  3.0
1  4  5  6.0
2  7  8  9.0

